# Appropriate Windows Hardware Lab Kit Selections in Device manager for a WFP driver

Tags: wfp

What device manager selections in Windows Hardware Lab Kit (HLK) I should use for setting up WHQL for a windows filtering platform driver?

When I build my project in HLK I see many options in the Select (device manager) section and I'm unsure of how to proceed.  Am I missing some additional file I'd load in to provide a WFP option?  I see I can load in test playlists but before I do that I must first select something in this area.

Microsoft docs don't seem to cover this for WFP.  Before I go back to the developers, I'd like to have a good idea what it is I'm looking for.

Do you know of good documents or references on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI for HLK studio can be challenging.

In selection, do not choose device manager as this is for hardware.  Instead, select **software device**.  Provided you installed your driver prior to installing the client, you should see it.